# set height of html element not working

Tags: html, css

why does html elements have the max-height attribute if they are not going to follow it. For example I have the table:

```
<table  border="2" style="table-layout:fixed; max-height:20px;">
    <tr style="height:20px;">
        <td style="overflow:hidden; max-height:20px; overflow:hidden;">
            <img id="book" src="img/capture.png" alt="" style="position:relative; margin-top:0px;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and if the img happens to have a height greater than 20px the table row's height will not equal 20px. How can I tell html that I want the table row to have a height of 20px?

Edit:

I know I can change the img height but I don't want to distort the img.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely has to do with the fact that `td` isn't `display:block`, but actually `display:table-cell`.  I don't think display table-cell supports `max-height`.

Is there a reason you don't want to set the height on the `<img>` tag?

See also:  [Setting max-height for table cell contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045653/setting-max-height-for-table-cell-contents)

Answer (score 1):

The table element is flexible enough to resize and accommodate it's content. It really isn't constraint by any max-heights.