# Two divs on top op each other, together exact height 100% + lower div scrollable

Tags: css, html, height, scrollable

I'm stuck with this problem:

I have a div (#container) which contains two divs. The height of the container should be exact 100%, regardless of the content of this div - not less not more.

Inside this div I want two full-width divs on top of each other:

- The (#upper) div's content automatically determines its height.
- The (#lower) div's content should be scrollable, but only vertically. Its height is dependent on the height of (#upper): 100% - (#upper)height = (#lower)height

Currently I have the following css ...

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
#container 
    {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: #f00;
    }
#upper { 
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #0f0;
    }
#lower {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00f;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

... as well as this code:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="upper"></div>
<div id="lower"></div>
</div>
```

How can the (#container)'s height be exactly 100% - independent of its content? Now the height becomes larger because of the combined content of (#upper) and (#lower)?

How can (#lower) be scrollable (only up and down, not left to right!)?

Thank you very much for your feedback, I hope we can all learn from this.

Comment: Regarding the scrolling in #lower, change to overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: When you say height should be 100%, are you talking about 100% of the screensize?

Comment: Thank you for your replies kunalbhat; indeed, 100% of screensize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set your `html` and `body` elements to have a height of 100%, so your children divs know what to base the percentage off of. Like so:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Change your container to this:

```
#container 
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

As for your scrolling issue, you're almost there. Change the code to the following:

```
#lower {
    width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #00f;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

For it to work best, have a fixed height set on your lower div and that'll make it easy for the scrollable action to work best.

EDIT:

I realized I mis-read your question. You'd like to have your lower div fill the remaining height of the window. Here's how to do that in jquery:

```
var top = $('#upper').height();
var remaining_height = parseInt($(window).height() - top); 
$('#lower').height(remaining_height);
```

I still haven't found a way to do that with only CSS... Sadly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @jbw91. Is there a reason why I cannot use the "position: relative" for #container? I can't use a fixed height for the #lower div: the #upper div's content determines its height en the #lower div must connect. In other words, the #lower div should fill the space between the #upper div and the screen bottom.

Comment: No, you can use <code>position:relative;</code>. I forgot to include that. :) As for your question about the lower div filling the rest of the screen's height, I mis-read your question. I've updated my answer to include a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @jbw91! Now it works properly! I just added the # to the $('lower') ;) I accepted your answer.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out! Just updated for anyone else. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think this may help you:

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .upper{
            height:50px;
            border: 1px solid groove;
        }
        .lower{
            height:calc(100% - 50px);
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height:500px; border:1px solid red; position:relative;">
        <div class="upper"></div>
        <div class="lower"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This will take 50px out the lower div

Answer (score 1):

For a pure CSS solution, use display: table-row.

```
<style>
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;padding:0;
}
  html, body, #container{
    height: 100%;
}

#container{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
}

#upper, #lower{
    display: table-row;
}

#upper{
    height: 100px;
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <div id="upper">bla</div>
    <div id="lower">bla</div>
</div>
```

This solution only works if the height of the content is not more than 100%, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13668087/603569

Answer (score 0):

Here a 100% css alternative:

```
<div style="height:100%;">
    main div

    <div style="height:100%;padding-bottom:200px;">
    header div
    </div>

    <div style="position:relative;height:200px;top:-200px;">
    footer div
    </div>

</div>
```

Remember that all parent elements, including body and html, must have their height set too.