# Completety unchangeable height and witdth for table cells

Tags: html, css

I want to create completely unchangeable height and width for my table cells. I only exclusively want to use HTML and CSS, no Javascript for that. My current setup looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    {{ template_head |safe }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/standard_report.css' %}">
    <style>
      {{ css_styles }}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    {{ images |safe }}
    {{ template_body |safe }}
    <table id="report_table" class="reportTable">
      <tr>
        <th id="th_week_day" class="thWeekDay">Tag</th>
        <th id="th_completed_task" class="thCompletedTask">Verrichtete Arbeit</th>
        <th id="th_hours_worked" class="hoursWorked">Zeit</th>
        <th id="th_working_department" class="thWorkingDepartment">Abteilung</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="week_day" class="weekDay">Mo.</td>
        <td id="completed_task" class="completedTask">Foo foo foo foo fooo foo foo fooooo fooo foo fooo foooo fooo fooof ooo foo foo foo fo o foo fooo fooof oofo ofoo fooof oofo ofooo fooofoo ofooo fooofo ofoo fooo fooo fooof ooof ooofo oofooof oofoo fooofo oo fooo fooof oofo ofoo fooof oofo ofooo fooofoo ofooo fooofo ofoo fooo fooo fooof oo fooo fooof oofo ofoo fooof oofo ofooo fooofoo ofooo fooofo ofoo fooo fooo fooof oo fooo fooof oofo ofoo fooof oofo ofooo fooofoo ofooo fooofo ofoo fooo fooo fooof oo fooo fooof oofo ofoo fooof oofo ofooo fooofoo ofooo fooofo ofoo fooo fooo fooof oo</td>
        <td id="hours_worked" class="hoursWorked">2</td>
        <td id="working_department" class="workingDepartment">Forschung und Entwicklung</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="week_day" class="weekDay">Di.</td>
        <td id="completed_task" class="completedTask">Bar</td>
        <td id="hours_worked" class="hoursWorked">4</td>
        <td id="working_department" class="workingDepartment">Technik</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="week_day" class="weekDay">Mi.</td>
        <td id="completed_task" class="completedTask">Baz</td>
        <td id="hours_worked" class="hoursWorked">5</td>
        <td id="working_department" class="workingDepartment">Forschung und Entwicklung</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="week_day" class="weekDay">Do.</td>
        <td id="completed_task" class="completedTask">Lorem</td>
        <td id="hours_worked" class="hoursWorked">3</td>
        <td id="working_department" class="workingDepartment">Forschung und Entwicklung</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="week_day" class="weekDay">Fr.</td>
        <td id="completed_task" class="completedTask">Ipsum</td>
        <td id="hours_worked" class="hoursWorked">5</td>
        <td id="working_department" class="workingDepartment">Technik</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td id="week_day" class="weekDay">Sa.</td>
        <td id="completed_task" class="completedTask"></td>
        <td id="hours_worked" class="hoursWorked">5</td>
        <td id="working_department" class="workingDepartment">Technik</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    width: 21cm;
    height: 29.7cm;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

table.reportTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#report_table {
    width: 16cm;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#th_week_day {
    width: 1cm;
    max-width: 1cm;
}

#week_day {
    width: 1cm;
    max-width: 1cm;
    height: 2.5cm;
    max-height: 2.5cm;
    text-align: center;
}

#completed_task {
    width: 7cm;
    max-width: 7cm;
    height: 2.5cm;
    max-height: 2.5cm;
    text-align: justify;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#hours_worked {
    width: 0.5cm;
    max-width: 0.5cm;
    height: 2.5cm;
    max-height: 2.5cm;
    text-align: center;
}

#working_department {
    width: 1.5cm;
    max-width: 1.5cm;
    height: 2.5cm;
    max-height: 2.5cm;
    text-align: center;
}
```

The width and height of the table cells unfortunately doesn't apply anymore and gets expanded when the text is too long. I made a test and inserted a lot of *foos* and the cell expanded like this:

[image]

When I tried `inline=block` all the cells moved to another place in the file. Can you guys tell me how my stupid boxes just keep the height and width that I tell them to have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you must use interior elements to set your heights. Wrap all cell content in divs and apply your IDs there. Better, use common classes, which are reusable.

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qvnzfnqg/1/)**

```
<td>
    <div id="completed_task" class="completedTask"> ... </div>
</td>
```

[More on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667941/how-to-set-maximum-height-for-table-cell)

Also, you're re-using IDs of the same value. This is invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that helped so far. But how can I use the same setup for more `<td>`'s then with out re-using the same ID's all the time?

Comment: @IbrahimApachi Use classes instead of id's, like this `.completedTask { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Please set a fixed height for you td you dont want to expand and use overflow-y:auto.so that if the content increases scroll bar will appear.