# How to set and fix html5 table column size dyamicly using knockout

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I have table like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: { data: dataset, as: 'rowInfo' }">
        <tr style="max-height: 30px" 
            data-bind="foreach: { data: $parent.metadata, as: 'colInfo' }">
            <td style="max-height: 30px" data-bind="text: rowInfo[colInfo.DataColumn],
                attr: {width: Width}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to have a grid like experience. So I don't want the text to wrap in the cell or make the cells to resize.
I want to have fixed sized cells which their `height` set to `30px` and the `width` set to the `colInfo.Width` which comes from knockout.

But with the above code, the cells re-size to fit their content. How should I set the attributes to have fixed `height` and `width`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a `max-height` to cell contents [you'll need to wrap it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045653/setting-max-height-for-table-cell-contents) in another element (e.g. a `div`). In addition, I'd recommend using the `style` binding, like this:

```
        <td>
        <div data-bind="text: rowInfo[colInfo.DataColumn],
            style: { width: Width, height: '30px' }"></div>
        </td>
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqqPj/) for a working demo.

Comment: Thanks it works great. But it seems it is illegal to use `div` in `th` for headers.

Comment: Glad it works. PS. According to [the spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-th-element) and [the validator](http://validator.w3.org/) it's legal to use a div in a th.