# Fix the length of a table for a dynamic length content

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I want to fix the height of a table which is going to show a dynamic string, the length of the string is variable, but the problem the row of the table is growing or minimizing according to the string to display
my CSS :

```
    #subscriberVehicle {
       width: 100%;
       height: 5%;
    }

   #subscriberVehicle table {
      table-layout: fixed;
       height: 5%;
       width: 100%;
    }
  #subscriberVehicle .col-3 {
     padding-top: 125px;
     height: 30%;
     width: 25%;
      max-height: 10px;     
   }
```

and the HTML file :

```
     <table id="attestation" class="row">
  <tr>
    <td class="col">
      <div id="subscriberVehicle" class="block">
        <table class="data">
          <tr style="height: 10px">
            <td class="col-3 content"><%= subscriber.entity.address %></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want the `tr` to have fixed height?

Comment: yes that is what i want

Comment: This will probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045653/setting-max-height-for-table-cell-contents

Comment: thanks ^ it is resolved by puttong a div inside the tr having this css class style="height:40px; overflow:hidden"

Comment: Please add another class to the col-3 one. It's not the best practice to edit the bootstrap classes.